# Set a Javascript Timer to Half hour

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I need to make a timer that counts down to 4:30pm. So far, I can get it to either 4pm or 5pm, but not any minutes in between. I've managed to figure this much out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var currentTime = new Date();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];

var suffix = "AM";

var hoursLeft = 16 - hours;
var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;

if (minutes < 10){ 
minutes = "0" + minutes;
 }

if (hours >= 18)
{
 document.write("Same day shipping has ended for today.");
} else

if ((n === "Saturday") || (n === "Sunday"))
{
document.write("Same day shipping is not available today.");
} else {

if (hoursLeft === 0) {
    document.write(minsLeft + " minutes left to have your order shipped today!");
} else {
    if (hoursLeft === 1) {
        document.write(hoursLeft + " hour and " + minsLeft + " minutes left to have your order shipped today!");
    } else {
    if ((hoursLeft === 0) && (minsLeft <= 30)){
    document.write(minsLeft + " minute left to have your order shipped today!");
    } else {

    if (minsLeft ===1) {
    document.write (hoursLeft + " hours and " + minsLeft + " minute left to have your order shipped today!");
    } else {


if(minsLeft===60){
minsLeft=0;
hoursLeft++;
n === "Monday";
n === "Tuesday";
n === "Wednesday";
n === "Thursday";
n === "Friday";
}

document.write(hoursLeft  + " hours and " + minsLeft + " minutes left to have your order shipped today!");
}
}
}
}
}

</script>
```

I need the time to count down to 4:30pm, but I've only figured out how to change the "var hoursLeft" to set it to "16 - hours" which gets me to 4pm, but can't figure out how to get it to 4:30pm. I thought I'd tweak the "var minsLeft" but got a weird bug that started to say stuff like "2 hours and -15 minutes left".

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do all the calculations in minutes, then divide by 60!

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter above suggested, do your calculations in minutes.  Convert your hours to total minutes and make sure the minutes are within your parameters.

For displaying the minutes, just use the modulo operator to get the number of minutes on top of the current hour.

For example, if there are 185 minutes left and you want to display "3 hours and 5 minutes left",

```
var minutesLeft = 185;
var hours = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
var minStr = minutesLeft % 60;
var timeLeft = hours + " hours and " + minStr + " minutes left";
```

You'll want to use your own logic, of course, to keep from saying things like "1 hours."

Comment: Thanks UtopiaLtd! Now I just need to figure out how to actually do that.